# Android update sum of value on each action made

Tags: java, android, checkbox, hashmap

I am doing an application where my textview updates itself immediately based on the checked checkbox and radio button. I have 3 hashmaps to store the values of each items:

```
    hashMap.put("chkCheese", 2.50);
    hashMap.put("chkPep", 3.50);
    hashMap.put("chkChick", 2.00);
    hashMap.put("chkBeef", 4.00);
    hashMap.put("chkBlackOlives", 2.00);
    hashMap.put("chkPine", 1.00);
    hashMap.put("chkMushroom", 1.00);
```

And this is my function to show items checked on change for my checkbox:

```
    private void checkEnoughAndMakeDisabled (CheckBox checkBoxes []) {
    int count = 0;
    for (CheckBox cb:checkBoxes) {
        cb.setEnabled(true);
        if (cb.isChecked()) {
            count++;
            toppingsSelection.add(cb);

        }
    }

    String text="";
    for (CheckBox items: toppingsSelection) {
        text = text + items.getText().toString() + ", ";
    }
    toppings.setText(text);

    if (count >= 5) {
        for (CheckBox cb:checkBoxes) {
            if (!cb.isChecked()) {
                cb.setEnabled(false);
            }
        }
    }
    toppingsSelection.clear();
}
```

Calling my function in onCreate():

```
        //Display TOPPINGS text on each action made
    final CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener chgListener = new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
            checkEnoughAndMakeDisabled(checkBox);
        }
    };

    for (CheckBox tmpCheckBox: checkBox) {

        tmpCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(chgListener);
    }
```

So far i can only show the name of items checked. I tried to do the similar stuff for my TextView priceSum to show the total sum but it doesnt work. I also tried putting the calculation and hashmap tag retrieval inside the checkEnoughAndMakeDisabled function, it crashes. How do you think is the best approach of getting the hashmap's value and do the calculation?
My attemp:

```
       //Display PRICE text on each action made
    price.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView textView, int i, KeyEvent keyEvent) {
            double cal=0.0;
            for (int y=0;y<checkBox.length;y++) {
                if (checkBox[y].isChecked()) {
                    toppingsSelection.add(checkBox[y]);
                }
            }
            for (CheckBox tmpTopping:toppingsSelection) {
                double toppingPriceSum = hashMap.get(tmpTopping.getTag());
                cal = cal + toppingPriceSum;
                String s = "RM " + toppingPriceSum;
                price.setText(s);
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You dont need loop for each time the user click instead make 1 method that saves data for you and you send boolen and value with it for example :

```
int total_price = 0 ;
private void UpdatePrice(boolean incremental,int value){
    if (incremental){
        total_price = total_price + value;
        Toast.makeText(this, String.valueOf(total_price), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }else {
        total_price = total_price - value;
        Toast.makeText(this, String.valueOf(total_price), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

and just call this method everytime he click `UpdatePrice(true,3);`

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it would be better to use ids for keys inside map - like:

```
val map = hashMapOf<Int, Double>()
map[R.id.chkCheese] = 2.50
map[R.id.chkPep] = 3.50
...
```

And inside your checkEnoughAndMakeDisabled:

```
var text = ""
var price = 0.0
toppingsSelection.forEach {
    text += it.text
    price += map[it.id] ?: 0.0
}
```

Sorry, not with java, but I think you'll understand

**UPD:**

Java:

```
String text = "";
double price = 0;
for (CheckBox checkBox : toppingsSelection) {
    text += checkBox.getText();
    price += map.get(checkBox.getId()) != null ? map.get(checkBox.getId()) : 0;
}
```

Comment: sorry i don't quite understand these two lines                                                  
    `text += it.text
    price += map[it.id] ?: 0.0`  are you saying that it loops through the items in toppingsSelection array and gets the correspond id in the hasmap to get and add the value?